# What is the context of this `JaxrsModule`?

Tags: jax-rs, guice, resteasy

In the following [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Guice1.html#d4e2119) it mentions `JaxrsModule`.

> **45.2. Binding JAX-RS utilities**
>
> Add the JaxrsModule to bind javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate,
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder,
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder,
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Variant.VariantListBuilder and
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientExecutor.

#### What is the context of this `JaxrsModule`?

Do they mean a `Guice` module, a `RestEasy Maven` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are referring to the guice module for RestEasy - https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-guice/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/guice/ext/JaxrsModule.java